# How to reuse assets in multiple scenes

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I want to **reuse assets** in multiple scenes, but I get this error:

```
Texture key already in use
```

Here is the relevant code.  Notice that I want to use the same spritesheet in both scenes.  How do I do that without getting this error?

```
class InventoryScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({ key: 'InventoryScene', active: true });
    }
    preload() {
        this.load.spritesheet('sheet1', 'assets/sheet1.png', 
            { frameWidth: 16, frameHeight: 16 });
    }
    create() {
        this.add.sprite(this.game.canvas.width * .50, 
                this.game.canvas.height * .50, 'sheet1')
            .setFrame(0)
            .setInteractive()
            .on('pointerdown', () => this.zoomIn())
            .setScale(6);
    }
}
class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({ key: 'GameScene', active: true });
    }
    preload() {
        this.load.spritesheet('sheet1', 'assets/sheet1.png', 
            { frameWidth: 16, frameHeight: 16 });
    }
    create() {
        this.add.sprite(this.game.canvas.width * .50, this
                .game.canvas.height * .50, 'sheet1')
            .setFrame(0)
            .setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Here is my game config:

```
var config = {
    ...
    // Order here matters.  The first scene is listed last.
    scene: [DebugScene, InventoryScene, GameScene, HowToPlayScene, TitleScene]
};
```

Then I use `this.scene.bringToTop('HowToPlayScene')` to activate a scene.

PS: I am using Phaser 3

Comment: Did you try make load only once in startup gamescene and remove in preload()  in others.

Comment: Good question, @Oleg.  I will add some more info to the question that might help answer it.  I am loading all my scenes in the config.  I think they all load at the same time.  Then I use `this.scene.bringToTop('HowToPlayScene')` to activate a scene.

Comment: @Oleg, yes I did try that, but I get a broken image.

Answer (score 2):

I created for you modified example with Phaser v3.17.

Copy Paste the code below and replace exist one in the page.
Click on 'Run Code' button on the top of the screen and may be have to wait 5-10 seconds:
https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/scenes/changing%20scene.js

Scenes will be changed by click on first scene and others in loop.
Pay attention on "face" and  "balls" spritesheet that was loaded only in first scene and this.scene.start('sceneB');

```
var SceneA = new Phaser.Class({

    Extends: Phaser.Scene,

    initialize:

    function SceneA() {
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, { key: 'sceneA' });
    },

    preload: function () {
        this.load.image('face', 'assets/pics/bw-face.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('balls', 'assets/sprites/balls.png', { frameWidth: 17, frameHeight: 17 });
    },

    create: function () {
        this.add.sprite(400, 300, 'face').setAlpha(0.2);
        this.add.sprite(400, 300, 'balls', 3);
        this.input.once('pointerdown', function () {

            console.log('From SceneA to SceneB');

            this.scene.start('sceneB');

        }, this);
    }

});

var SceneB = new Phaser.Class({

    Extends: Phaser.Scene,

    initialize:

    function SceneB() {
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, { key: 'sceneB' });
    },

    preload: function () {
        this.load.image('arrow', 'assets/sprites/longarrow.png');
    },

    create: function () {

        this.add.sprite(400, 300, 'face').setAlpha(1);
        this.arrow = this.add.sprite(400, 300, 'arrow').setOrigin(0, 0.5);
        this.add.sprite(400, 300, 'balls', 3);
        this.input.once('pointerdown', function (event) {

            console.log('From SceneB to SceneC');

            this.scene.start('sceneC');

        }, this);
    },

    update: function (time, delta) {
        this.arrow.rotation += 0.01;
    }

});

var SceneC = new Phaser.Class({

    Extends: Phaser.Scene,

    initialize:

    function SceneC() {
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, { key: 'sceneC' });
    },

    preload: function () {
        this.load.image('mech', 'assets/pics/titan-mech.png');
    },

    create: function () {
        this.add.sprite(Phaser.Math.Between(0, 800), 300, 'mech');
        this.add.sprite(400, 300, 'balls', 3);
        this.input.once('pointerdown', function (event) {

            console.log('From SceneC to SceneA');

            this.scene.start('sceneA');

        }, this);
    }

});

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    scene: [SceneA, SceneB, SceneC]
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

Comment: This is a helpful answer.  Thank you!  I will try to implement this and I will accept the answer after that.  :)

Comment: Hi, did you try?